# SharePoint 2010 Site Collection Administration option

Tags: sharepoint, collections, administrator

"In order to see the Site Collection Administration section in the Site Setting you have to be Site Collection Administrator. If you are only the site owner, the Site Collection Administration option will not be available. Once you have that level of permission you can enable publishing Infrastructure. As Dung said go to Site Collection Administration - Site collection features."

QUESTION: 
How do you enable 'Site Collection Administrator' privilege? I am a farm admin with Full Control according to sharepoint. I need to see the Site Collection Administration option.

Comment: This should be moved to [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-2010)

Comment: Belongs to sharepoint q&a site

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Central Administration website -> `Application Management` -> `Change site collection administrators`
Add your account as either the primary or secondary site collection administrator.

Or within the website itself drop down `Site Actions`, choose -> `Site Settings` -> `Site collection administrators`

Not that the farm admin may not have permissions on the site to get to the Site settings of an individual site collection, so may have to use central admin to add themselves as a site collection administrator, then go to the site collection and alter the site collection administrators.

[From Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631156.aspx)

1.
Verify that you have the following administrative credentials:
 To add a site collection administrator, you must be a member of the Farm Administrators group on the computer that is running the SharePoint Central Administration Web site.

2.
On the home page of the SharePoint Central Administration Web site, select Application Management.

3.
On the Application Management page, under Site Collections, select Change site collection administrators.

4.
On the Site Collection Administrators page, click the arrow next to the site collection name and select Change Site Collection.

5.
If the site collection to which you want to add an administrator is listed, select the URL of the site collection and then click OK. If the site collection is not listed, click the arrow next to the Web application name; click Change Web Application; select the name of the Web application that contains the site collection; select the URL of the site collection; and then click OK.

6.
In the Secondary Site Collection Administrator area, either type the name of the user whom you want to add by using the format \ or select the user by using the address book.

7.
Click OK.

Comment: I'm sorry. I need to see the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" option.

QUESTION: How do you enable 'Site Collection Administrator' privilege? I am a farm admin with Full Control according to sharepoint. I need to see the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" option.

http://www.sperrgebiet.org/2010/03/an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-when-trying-to-create-an-enterprise-search-center-in-sharepoint-2010/

I am experiencing that error when trying to use the change request management template i deployed on SharePoint.

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The answer does not change, you have to go to central admin and add yourself there.

Comment: Nat...can you help me with this related one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670643/how-to-use-change-request-management-template-in-sharepoint-2010